# Joint exponential distribution

Tags: probability

Let Z be the circumference of a rectangle with sides of length X and Y
A and Y are independed and distributed exponentially both with $ \lambda =1$

What is the probability that a circle with radius r fits completely inside the rectangle?

I think I need to calculate $P(2r \le min (X,Y))= 1 - ( P(2r \geq X) \cup P(2r\geq Y))$  but I'm not sure how to procede.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Good idea, not quite there.  If the minimum of two variables is greater than some constant, then both of the variables are.  No need for complements.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(\min(X,Y) \geq 2r) ~{= P(X \geq 2r, Y \geq 2r) \\= P(X \geq 2r)\,P(Y \geq 2r)\\  =  (1-P(X<2r))\,(1-P(Y<2r)) \\ = e^{-2r}\cdot e^{-2r} }$$